# Proof that $\zeta {\space(3)} = \frac{5}{2} \sum{(-1)^{n-1}/{n^3}{2n\choose{n}}}$ and generalizations.

Tags: riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

How do I show:
$$\zeta {\space(3)} = \frac{5}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{{{n^3}{2n\choose{n}}}}}$$
and if I want to generalize for any value of the zeta function what do I have to change, the $n^3$ term?

Comment: The bounds are not there and the fraction is vague.  $(a/b)c\stackrel?=a/bc\stackrel?=a/(bc)$

Comment: Related: [What is the binomial sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^5\,\binom {2n}n}$ in terms of zeta functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144985/what-is-the-binomial-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n5-binom-2nn-in-term?rq=1)

Comment: Ok, will fix that now